# Animations for C# .net programming

Tags: c#, winforms, events, animation

I am currently working on a project in which I am developing an app with C# .net.

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010, and I am wondering how I can add some animations and effects to the app?

In my implementation I've enabled moving panels up and down, hiding panels, etc.

My question is, how can I add effects (fading, jQuery-like effects...) to those events?

Comment: What kind of app? Web, WPF, Silverlight, console app, windows forms?

Comment: You've tagged this as WinForms, but if you could use WPF instead you'd find a *huge* amount of support for animation built in...

Answer (score 4):

WinForms is not the idea framework for the effects you have discribed, it is arguably better to  change from WInForms to [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) which was designed for these types of effects and 2D/3D rendering.

[WPF Graphics and Multimedia](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742562.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Lloyd. I want to use effects in some certain places in my app, and I want the effects to be simple (and not 3D for example). Is there any effects for panel movement, scrolling down/up...?

Comment: What type of "scrolling", There is the ScrollViewer  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated, I would look to WPF for these kind of things. If for some reason WPF is not available, you could look to third party libraries for these kind of things, such as [Animated Vector Graphics](http://www.vgdotnet.com/) (commercial).